# Why is the Photon.Engine MasterClient player not visible on the screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am developing a project in Unity with Photon.Engine, but I have a problem. The other player appears on the MasterClient player's screen, but the MasterClint player is not visible on the other player. When the other player enters the room, "Received OnSerialization for view ID 1001. We have no such PhotonView! Ignore this if you're joining or leaving a room. State: Joined'' warning appears. Photon.View,Photon.transform and photon.Animator scripts are attached to the character.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to disable/remove a camera that doesn't belong to you, for example:

`if (!PhotonView.isMine) playerCamera.gameObject.SetActive(false);`

And you should use and attach it in unity to `[SerializeField] private Camera playerCamera;` to define camera object.

Comment: Thanks for your help but that didn't work. :(

Comment: Can you show a bit of  your connecting script? Also how do you instantiate player objects?